# How pass javascript function value into input tag value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below My javascript code. I want to show current date and time into my **input** disabled tag.

```
function getDateTime() {
  var now     = new Date(); 
  var year    = now.getFullYear();
  var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
  var day     = now.getDate();
  var hour    = now.getHours();
  var minute  = now.getMinutes();
  var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
  if(month.toString().length == 1) {
    var month = '0'+month;
  }
  if(day.toString().length == 1) {
    var day = '0'+day;
  }   
  if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
     var hour = '0'+hour;
  }
  if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
    var minute = '0'+minute;
  }
  if(second.toString().length == 1) {
    var second = '0'+second;
  }   
  var dateTime = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+' '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
  return dateTime;
}
```

HTML code is

```
<input type="textbox" name="inDate" id="indate" onload="this.value=getDateTime()" class="field left" disabled   />
```

But it don't works. Give me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code :

```
<input type="textbox" name="inDate" id="indate" class="field left" disabled   />
```

Script : -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#indate').val(getDateTime());
});

function getDateTime() {
  var now     = new Date(); 
  var year    = now.getFullYear();
  var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
  var day     = now.getDate();
  var hour    = now.getHours();
  var minute  = now.getMinutes();
  var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
  if(month.toString().length == 1) {
    var month = '0'+month;
  }
  if(day.toString().length == 1) {
    var day = '0'+day;
  }   
  if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
     var hour = '0'+hour;
  }
  if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
    var minute = '0'+minute;
  }
  if(second.toString().length == 1) {
    var second = '0'+second;
  }   
  var dateTime = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+' '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
  return dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use the `ready` event and set the value there

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#indate').val(getDateTime());
});
```

Comment: Will I write it another script or same script? And what will the html is?

Comment: @MasudSarker, leave the HTML like it was but remove onload="..."

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add the value to Markup (i.e DOM). Your function is not doing this, it is only returning the value and storing it internally.

Instead, try using javascript to add HTML(injecting the value as new element to DOM). jQuery makes it easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#indate').val(getDateTime();
});
```